# Multiple control chart EWMA RStudio

Tags: r

I am trying plot multiples control chart type EWMA in just a plot in software RStudio, using the function par, but, there aren't output error and the each controlchart is plotted in the same local graph, not in the different position.

`par(mfrow=c(2,2),new=TRUE) q2 <-  ewma(x2,center = 0,  lambda=0.4,std.dev=0.57, nsigmas=3,add.stats='False') par(new=TRUE) q3 <-  ewma(x3,center = 0,  lambda=0.4,std.dev=0.57, nsigmas=3,add.stats='False') #par(new=TRUE) q4 <-  ewma(x4,center = 0,  lambda=0.4,std.dev=0.57, nsigmas=3,add.stats='False') #par(new=TRUE) q5 <-  ewma(x5,center = 0,  lambda=0.4,std.dev=0.57, nsigmas=3,add.stats='False')`

I would like to plot four control chart in this plot, but, actually, each control chart is insert in the same position:

[image]

Comment: This can easily be achieved by using either `ggplot`, `gridExtra` or both. It would be helpful if you can include a sample of your data in this question e.g. by  using `dput(head(data))`

Comment: Thanks for help, i tried the command (`grid.arrange(q2,q3,q4,q5,nrow=2,ncol=2)`), but appear the follow error message (Error in gList(list(call = ewma(data = x2, center = 0, std.dev = 0.57,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList") , Could you help me?

Comment: Combine your plots in a list (`plot_list`) and then: `do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_list, nrow = x, ncol = y))` with x and y being the number of row and columns in the plot.

Comment: Hi Paul Van Oppen, First of all, thanks for help me, but the error appear yet. I used the follow syntax (`plot_list=list(q2,q3,q4,q5)
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_list, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))`), results the error message (`Error in gList(list(call = ewma(data = x2, center = 0, std.dev = 0.57,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`). There are other possibiliy to plot this? I need the high resolution to insert a academic paper. I am very grateful.

Comment: can you edit your question and add all relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further inspection, the problem is caused by the `plot.ewma.qcc` function from the `qcc` package not returning a grob. So we need to convert these objects to grobs first. `cowplot` gives us a way to do this:

```
library(qcc)
library(gridExtra)
library(cowplot)

data(pistonrings)
attach(pistonrings)
diameter <- qcc.groups(diameter, sample)

q2 <-
  ~ ewma(
    diameter[1:25, ],
    center = 0,
    lambda = 0.4,
    std.dev = 0.57,
    nsigmas = 3,
    add.stats = FALSE
  ) 

q3 <-
  ~ ewma(
    diameter[15:40, ],
    center = 0,
    lambda = 0.4,
    std.dev = 0.57,
    nsigmas = 3,
    add.stats = 'False'
  ) 

plot_list <- list(p1 = as_grob(q2), p2 = as_grob(q3))
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_list, ncol = 2))
```

Note the tilde `~` formula operator in front of the calls to the `ewma` function calls. This is how `cowplot` wants it. We then call the `cowplot::as_grob` function when we compile the plots into a list. `do.call` and `grid.arrange` do the rest.
Which generates this plot:

[image]

Note: I am not very familiar with `cowplot` so it escaped me that this package has a method for grid plotting:

```
plot_grid(q2, q3, labels = c('A', 'B'), label_size = 12)
```

Which would give you the same results as above.

Comment: Dear Paul van Oppen,  Thank you very much to help, in this way worked!! I am very grateful to patiente and willing to help!